# Appropriately Release Buffers From AVCaptureDataOutputSynchronizerDelegate Due to Out Of Buffers

Tags: swift, buffer, avcapture, cmsamplebuffer

I am using `AVCaptureDataOutputSynchronizerDelegate` to handle capturing data for video, depth and metadata

```
    private let videoDataOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
    private let depthDataOutput = AVCaptureDepthDataOutput()
    private let metadataOutput = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()
```

So using the below code, I am able to get specifically video data within the delegate method used from `AVCaptureDataOutputSynchronizerDelegate`.

```
func dataOutputSynchronizer(_ synchronizer: AVCaptureDataOutputSynchronizer, didOutput synchronizedDataCollection: AVCaptureSynchronizedDataCollection) {

    guard let syncedVideoData = synchronizedDataCollection.synchronizedData(for: self.videoDataOutput) as? AVCaptureSynchronizedSampleBufferData else { return }
```

The problem is, when I try to save the videoData into an array as below, I get a [OutOfBuffers](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcaptureoutput/datadroppedreason/outofbuffers) error. This problem persists if I try to save the videoData/the imagery associated/anything related to this data.

```
let array:[CMSampleBuffer] = []

...

array.append(syncedVideoData)
//Gets to about 5-6 sets of data, then it runs out of buffers. 
//I think the buffer is being retained permanently since I am saving to a global variable here.
//Leading to out of buffer error
```

So, what I am thinking is happening is that **since I am saving any related data into an array, it is keeping the data in the buffer in memory whereas it is normally released.**

The [webpage linked earlier for OutOfBuffers](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcaptureoutput/datadroppedreason/outofbuffers) indicates that I can

> If you need to perform extended processing of captured data, copy that data into buffers whose lifetimes you manage instead of relying on buffers vended by the capture output.

I attempted to create a new `CMSampleBuffer`

```
extension VideoCapture: AVCaptureDataOutputSynchronizerDelegate {

func dataOutputSynchronizer(_ synchronizer: AVCaptureDataOutputSynchronizer, didOutput synchronizedDataCollection: AVCaptureSynchronizedDataCollection) {

    var newData:CMSampleBuffer?

    guard let syncedVideoData = synchronizedDataCollection.synchronizedData(for: self.videoDataOutput) as? AVCaptureSynchronizedSampleBufferData else { return }
    guard !syncedVideoData.sampleBufferWasDropped else {
        print(syncedVideoData.droppedReason.rawValue)
        return
    }
    let videoSampleBuffer = syncedVideoData.sampleBuffer

    CMSampleBufferCreateCopy(allocator: kCFAllocatorDefault, sampleBuffer: videoSampleBuffer, sampleBufferOut: &newData)
    if(newData != nil) {
        self.buffer.append(newData!)
    }
}
```

but this causes the same issues -- the videoData is still staying in the buffer. I get to about 5-6 sets of videoData and then I get no more datums.

Any guidance on how to *"copy that data into buffers whose lifetimes you manage instead of relying on buffers vended by the capture output."* as indicated on [the outOfBuffers website](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcaptureoutput/datadroppedreason/outofbuffers)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to create a buffer following [this buffer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/vimage/vimage_buffers) and [this guide](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/vimage/applying_vimage_operations_to_video_sample_buffers) and a few others in the Apple Docs.

```
...
guard let imagePixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(videoSampleBuffer) else { fatalError() }


//First lock buffer
CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imagePixelBuffer,
                                     CVPixelBufferLockFlags.readOnly)

//Do something with buffer
self.buffer = createMyBuffer(pixelBuffer: imagePixelBuffer)

//Unlock buffer
CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imagePixelBuffer,
                                       CVPixelBufferLockFlags.readOnly)
self.doSomething(self.buffer)

...

func createMyBuffer(pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer) -> CVPixelBuffer? {
    let scaleWidth:Int = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(pixelBuffer)
    let scaleHeight:Int = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(pixelBuffer)

    let flags = CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: 0)
    guard kCVReturnSuccess == CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, flags) else {
        return nil
    }

    defer { CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, flags) }

    guard let srcData = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pixelBuffer) else {
        print("Error: could not get pixel buffer base address")
        return nil
    }

    let srcBytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(pixelBuffer)
    var srcBuffer = vImage_Buffer(data: srcData,
                                      height: vImagePixelCount(CVPixelBufferGetHeight(pixelBuffer)),
                                      width: vImagePixelCount(CVPixelBufferGetWidth(pixelBuffer)),
                                      rowBytes: srcBytesPerRow)

    let destBytesPerRow = scaleWidth*4
    guard let destData = malloc(scaleHeight*destBytesPerRow) else {
        print("Error: out of memory")
        return nil
    }

    var destBuffer = vImage_Buffer(data: destData,
                                       height: vImagePixelCount(scaleHeight),
                                       width: vImagePixelCount(scaleWidth),
                                       rowBytes: destBytesPerRow)

    let error = vImageScale_ARGB8888(&srcBuffer, &destBuffer, nil, vImage_Flags(kvImageLeaveAlphaUnchanged))
    if error != kvImageNoError {
        print("Error:", error)
        free(destData)
        return nil
    }

    let releaseCallback: CVPixelBufferReleaseBytesCallback = { _, ptr in
        if let ptr = ptr {
            free(UnsafeMutableRawPointer(mutating: ptr))
        }
    }

    let pixelFormat = CVPixelBufferGetPixelFormatType(pixelBuffer)
    var dstPixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer?
    let status = CVPixelBufferCreateWithBytes(nil, scaleWidth, scaleHeight,
                                                  pixelFormat, destData,
                                                  destBytesPerRow, releaseCallback,
                                                  nil, nil, &dstPixelBuffer)
    if status != kCVReturnSuccess {
        print("Error: could not create new pixel buffer")
        free(destData)
        return nil
    }
    return dstPixelBuffer
}
```

This works - but seems redundant. I'm using a function I found that "scales" the buffer, but I just scale it to the exact same size as the current buffer and it returns a new buffer that I delete when I choose to. It is repetitive, but the functionality works.